# R convert numeric variable to factor

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

**UPDATE** I found solution to my problem, following code gives me correct answer

```
animaldata$myfac <- with(animaldata, recode(Age.Intake, "lo:0=1; 1:hi=2; else=2"))
animaldata$myfac = factor(animaldata$myfac)
levels(animaldata$myfac) <- list(young = 1, adult = 2)
table(animaldata$myfac)

young adult 
  191   282
```

**This question is not a duplicate of there other question using cut**

I am trying to convert a numerical variable to a factor based of condition on that variable. But I am unable to do so.

```
## load the librray
library(SDSFoundations) 

## load the datset
animaldata <- AnimalData

# Get age of each gender
table(animaldata$Sex , animaldata$Age.Intake)
```

Running the above command gives the following result

```
           0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  15  17
  Female  84  30  31  17  11  18   3   3   8   5   2   1   2   3   2   0
  Male   107  33  32  21  11  14  10  10   3   3   3   2   1   2   0   1
```

I want to create a factor variable **Age** with **2 levels** using the following conditions

```
If animaldata$Age.Intake < 1 then young
else adult
```

I have tried using `cut` but got in correct result

```
table(cut(animaldata$Age.Intake,breaks = c(0, 1, Inf), labels = c("young", "adult")))

young adult 
   63   219
```

**UPDATE 2** I tried `include.lowest = TRUE` but I am still getting incorrect result.

```
table(cut(animaldata$Age.Intake,breaks = c(0, 1, Inf), labels = c("young", "adult"),include.lowest = TRUE))

young =254 and adult= 219
```

Comment: have a look at `?cut`

Comment: I did, but could not figure out who to use it ```cut(animaldata$Age.Intake,breaks = 0:1, labels = c("young", "adult"))```

Comment: Try `breaks = c(0, 1, Inf)`

Comment: Running ```table(cut(animaldata$Age.Intake,breaks = c(0, 1, Inf), labels = c("young", "adult")))``` gives me ***63 young and 219 adults*** which is incorrect

Comment: Check the other arguments of `?cut` - you may need to change `include.lowest = TRUE`

Comment: @user20650 It wrong because young should be aged less than 1 which means 84+107 = 191, the other group should be 282

Comment: duh...sorry. Also use `right=FALSE`

Comment: @user20650 See update in OP

Comment: You could also use `factor(age >= 1 , c(FALSE, TRUE), labels = c("young", "adult"))` or `?ifelse` amongst others. Got there in the end.